# I'm trying to set a footer with css and I need to have 2 lines

Tags: html, css, pdf, visualforce

I have this css:

```
            @page {
            size: letter;
            margin: 15mm;
            @top-center {
                font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
                content: "Header stuff- blah blah";
            }

            @bottom-center {
                content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
            }

        }
```

I have a Visualforce page that is converted into a PDF and the CSS works great at giving a page counter on the bottom of every page. Ultimately a VF page just has html contained in it.

I want to add a URL that appears in the footer above the page counter on every page and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two things:

- inject the newline which normally isn't allowed in `content`, this can be done with `\A` (A in hexadecimal = 10 in decimal. "New line", commonly shown as `\n` is 10th character in ASCII tables)
- you need to respect that newline, out of the box multiple spaces, tabs etc are happily ignored in HTML (that's why we use `<br>` etc)

  ```
  <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" 
      standardStylesheets="false" readonly="true"
      renderAs="pdf">
      <html>
          <head>
              <style type="text/css">
              @page {
                  size: A5 landscape;
                  @bottom-right {
                      content: "https://stackoverflow.com\A" counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
                  white-space: pre-line;
                  }
              }
              </style>
          </head>
      </html>
  </apex:page>
  ```

Comment: That worked. And also thank you for the explanation @eyescream

Comment: Glad I could help! I remember it took me a while when I needed it. Crafting print-friendly pages is a bit of an art :) Good luck!